# Angular app being refreshed while navigating to routes in Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I have an angular app and in Microsoft Edge 16.16299 when I click on Router Links instead of simply change the route with animations I wrote, the whole app gets refreshed and then it loads the route. but it works ok on chrome. I found out that the problem is with a function call for clicking on the routerLink:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let link of item.items">
    <a routerLink="{{link.routerLink}}" [routerLinkActive]="'active active-link'" (click)="changeColorAndBreadCrumb($event,null)">{{link,label}}<a>
<mat-list-item>
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Add the code from one of the affected router links to your question.

Comment: unfortunately I can't add the code here. it's on another computer and it's not connected to the Internet and we can't transfer codes from it to another computer either.

Comment: Read one of the lines of code from the one machine, and enter it in here. It's virtually impossible to diagnose a code issue without code. My guess is that you're using <a href...> syntax in your routerLinks, and that's triggering Edge to load the main application URL first before the routerLink directs you to the correct path.

Comment: I don't use `href` for routerLinks. and it works on Chrome so there should be a problem in Edge.

Comment: OK I found the problem. in each router link I used `(click)="changeThemeColorAndBreadCrumb($event, null)"` function call. it makes the app refresh. in this method I just change the colors of header and sidenav based on the route. how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving this out of the comments:

> "OK I found the problem. in each router link I used
>   (click)="changeThemeColorAndBreadCrumb($event, null)" function call.
>   it makes the app refresh. in this method I just change the colors of
>   header and sidenav based on the route. how should I fix this?"

Either use the routerlink in the template directly, **or** use the click method, and redirect in the click method - **don't** use both.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) {}

changeThemeColorAndBreadCrumb(event,i) {
    // set color of header and sidenav here
     this.router.navigate(['/whatever-url-here']);
}
```